# Hot - not hot breaker w voltage tester

Tags: electrical

[image]working on a paint job in utility room. I was showing my wife how a voltage tester works. While the dead front cover was off, the breakers at the top of each row were showing hot w tester. When I re-installed the dead front, they were showing safe again. What am I not getting here?

Comment: Maybe the grounded cover is throwing it off. I never liked those testers.

Comment: I'm wondering if the close proximity to the main is causing the hot read and the cover is just enough to block it.

Comment: Does the voltage detector have a battery?

Answer (score 1):

Couple things come to mind.

1. That is a Fluke pen, they are pretty sensitive. I would measure the voltage by sticking it into the slot on terminal screw, not the top of the breaker itself
2. The front cover on that (what appears to be a sub panel) panel is entirely irrelevant for whether or not the circuits are hot. If you want to make sure it is off, you need to go to the main panel and disconnect it there since there doesn't seem to be a main disconnect (or input breaker) for that panel in the picture